# Trying to find whitespaces in String

Tags: java, string

I want to find if there are whitespaces in my string, and if there are, print if there are whitespaces, and if there are, print the longest word in the string.

What i've done so far is :

```
private static void stringFunc() {

    String s = new String("Crying to be heard");
    String rts = " ";
    String word[] = s.split(rts);

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i].length() >= rts.length()) {
            rts = word[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(rts);

}
```

Comment: What do you think would happen to `word[]` if there were no spaces? Also note that the first line should be written: `String s = "Crying to be heard";`

Comment: "Can't find it anywhere" isn't really a great description of your problem. What exactly isn't working? What can you not find?

Comment: 1. Can you clarify your request? 2. What is not working? From a little bit of testing I would say it works as intended

Comment: Why are you comparing `word[i].length()` against 1 (`rst.length()` will always be 1 because `String rts = " ";`? What do you think about this, maybe you need to compare `word[i].length()` against the longest length found yet?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza rts changes

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Please always include the current and the desired output.

Comment: What is your actual question? The code seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073886/oh-god-spiders, I'm trying to find if there are whitespaces in the string.
If there are, to print the longest word.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the longest word part of the problem sorted, you just need to work out whether the original string contains a space.

As assylias alludes, if there are no spaces in the string, you want to think about how many items will be in the array you create.  If that is the right amout you have no spaces.  If not, you do and need to run the 'longest word' part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void stringFunc() {
    String s = new String("Crying to be heard");
    String[] splits = s.split("\\s+");
    int largeIndex = -1;
    int maxLen = 0;

    if (splits.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            if (maxLen < splits[i].length()) {
                largeIndex = i;
                maxLen = splits[i].length();
            }
        }
    }
    if (largeIndex != -1)
        System.out.println(splits[largeIndex]);
    else
        System.out.println("No white spaces");

}
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you'll feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you've fed him for a lifetime."

Comment: Pleas highlight your changes and explain them in detail. Especially for those beginner level questions explanations help way more than only code.

Answer (score 0):

It won't contain spaces because you are splitting string with space.

`String word[] = s.split(rts);`

This already removed spaces from your string and now you are iterating on string that has no space.

I think he means something like this.

```
private static void stringFunc() {

    String s = new String("Crying to be heard");
    String rts = " ";
    String word[] = s.split(rts);
    if(s.contains(rts)) {
        System.out.println("There are spaces");
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (word[i].length() >= rts.length()) {
                rts = word[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rts);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think he refers to the original non-splitted string. The splitting part is only for finding the longest word that does not contain a whitespace.

Comment: He says "print if there are whitespaces".

Comment: Thanks Mujahid, it worked.
The if statement above, was what i lacked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner:

`String longest = Arrays.stream(word).sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.length())).reduce((a,  b) -> b).get();`

Basically, it streams your array and then sorts it based on the length of each element (word) and then picks the last word which is the word with the longest length.

Comment: The last word is not always the longest.

Comment: I ran this. I get "crying" which is the longest word in your sentence. Are you trying a different sentence?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @JohnMason, what is it printing in your case? It is printing "crying" in my case.

Comment: Exactly what it does.

Comment: Now nothing, i just forgot an if statement above the for loop, so it will tell me if there are whitespaces and print the longest word in the string.
Now it works perfect.

Comment: @JohnMason. There are 4 answers to your question here. You should 'accept' the one that best answered your question and upvote the remaining ones that provided helpful insight.